# How to dynamically import a component

Tags: vue-component, vue.js

I'm trying to create a generic form field in Vue that can be configured to use various different widgets for input. I'd like to have a directory of inputs and then import the correct one and use it in my component. So far I can't even get the import to work. This component is inspired by the Winterfell library for React that uses a schema to configure a form. I'm using Vue with the standard webpack loader and JSX.

Here's my simple FieldValue component so far. I'd like to be able to dynamically import a component such as ./inputs/TextInput (or anything else in the inputs subdir by name).

```
<script>

/* Schema format
    {
        id: 'ABCD',
        label: 'Some text',
        input: {
            type: theNameOfTheInputComponentToUse,
            options: {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
*/

var Inputs = require('./inputs');

export default {
    props: {
        schema: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        }
    },
    render: function(h) {
        // let Input = Inputs[this.schema.input.type];
        let Input = require('./inputs/' + this.schema.input.type);
        if (!Input) {
            throw new Error('Unknown Input Type "' + this.schema.input.type + '". This component should exist in the inputs folder.');
        }

        return (
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="{this.id}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{this.schema.label}</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    {JSON.stringify(this.schema)}
                    <input schema={this.schema} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
</script>
```

When I try to run the app it won't compile and I get the following error in the console:

```
This dependency was not found in node_modules:

* ./inputs
```

Any help getting this working is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module imports are already resolved during the build phase, before the code is actually running, so it's understandable you're getting that error.

You should just import all possible inputs and then just determine which one to use based on `this.schema.input.type`. Something like this:

```
const allInputs = {
  text: require('./inputs/text'),
  number: require('./inputs/number'),
}

const inputToUse = allInputs[this.schema.input.type]
```

It looks to me like you already had something similar in place, judging by the lines `var Inputs = require('./inputs');` and `// let Input = Inputs[this.schema.input.type];`

Comment: Thanks. This works with the caveat that I need to register in advance all the components in the inputs directory. Using require('./inputs') still results in a build error. I changed it to use dynamic components using the <component> tag instead of JSX and it seems to be working.

Comment: I believe `require('./inputs)` isn't some automatic way to import everything from a directory, but only tries to import `./inputs/index.js` by default. So it's up to you to make sure that file exists and imports all the others.